# Why does OpenAI Gym Atari give a wrong observation while rendering?

Tags: openai-gym

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyc0W.png)

This is what `env.render()` outputs on the screen, the environment is SpaceInvader-v0.

Am I doing something wrong here? My code is literally right off the OpenAI Gym website, only changed the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gym` and `atari_py` versions are incompatible (`atari_py >= 0.1.1` requires `gym >= 0.9.5`).

The openai devs [introduced `getScreenRGB2`](https://github.com/openai/atari-py/commit/5f2a36214c3bf659210ff7062de7a89f3fc470f3) API call and [changed `gym`](https://github.com/openai/gym/commit/3bc4692d12e0de70d401ad0f003ff2719f968e37) to use it after [my call](https://github.com/openai/atari-py/commit/a8024822f7677eb0609d7912b18134d9c69445fc#commitcomment-21523652) that `getScreenRGB` is actually returns data not in `RGB` but in `BGRX` format and latter channel swapping in `gym` eats a lot of CPU cycles.

Comment: I fixed this by just upgrading to the latest version of `gym`, but it's good to know what really caused the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and just figured it out (hopefully it's the same issue as yours).  I had installed gym==0.7.0 and all I could get is a jumbled screen.  When I upgraded to the latest gym (0.9.x), everything now looks correct.  You may have to modify some code to adapt to the version switch.