# How to install atari-py in Windows 10?

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install lib pack atari-py, and can not find any clear information, most of them wrote that it is no way to install this pack into Win 10 at moment.

> pip install gym[atari]

I have this error:

```
Unable to execute 'make build -C atari_py/ale_interface -j 3'. HINT: are you sure `make` is installed?
    error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

How to find this "make" file and configure it ?! Any information would be appreciated !

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605769/openai-gym-atari-on-windows/46739299

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/openai/gym:

> We currently support Linux and OS X running Python 2.7 or 3.5.

No Windows.