# how to install gym from tensorflow in Windows10

Tags: python, tensorflow, openai-gym

so i want to implement for the first time an algorithm for reinforcement learning for the smartcab problem but when i install the gym library there is a probleme (platform : Windows 10)

the CL used :

```
pip install cmake 'gym [atari]' scipy
```

the error is :

```
Unable to execute 'make build -C atari_py/ale_interface -j 3'. HINT: are you sure `make` is installed?
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install atari-py in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551549/how-to-install-atari-py-in-windows-10)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible since it's not supported on Windows sadly.

See the underlying link, someone else already had this problem.

[How to install atari-py in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551549/how-to-install-atari-py-in-windows-10)

Comment: This should be a comment or a flag to close as "Duplicate". If you don't have sufficient reputation to do either of those things, then it's best to do nothing.