# OpenAI Gym not rendering colors correctly in console environments

Tags: python, console-application, openai-gym

So I've just started using Gym from OpenAI and I'm trying to render an environment in the console. Specifically, it's the `Taxi-v2` environment. And where it's supposed to show colors it only shows symbols (their ANSI code I think) so I'd believe it's not parsing correctly. I've tried other environments that also render in console, same problem. I've tried using the Git Bash console as well as the Windows one, and it's the same problem as well. Any help?

Code to render:

```
import gym

env = gym.make('Taxi-v2')
env.render()
```

Output in console:

```
+---------+
|?[35mR?[0m: | : :G|
| : : :?[43m ?[0m: |
| : : : : |
| | : | : |
|Y| : |?[34;1mB?[0m: |
+---------+
```

Comment: Gym is not officially supported on windows and a lot of workarounds are needed to get it to work even minimally. You will have to supply more information on what all you installed to get it working to what it is now for anyone to help you.

Comment: @Bayko I'd believe it'd be the regular installing process. I installed Python 3.6 normally, then used pip to install Gym and then SciPy because it didn't work without it. I also have Git Bash installed and I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: That prolly doesnt do the whole dependencies and you might be missing out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605769/openai-gym-atari-on-windows

Comment: @Bayko huh, I think I have everything installed. I checked with the `show` command and I have `six`, `requests`, `numpy`, `pyglet` and `scipy`, all of them with the correct versions. The only thing left would be those `make` and `cmake` dependencies that question is talking about, but I think those are only for the Atari environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use **conemu** terminal which actually supports ANSI escape code.

https://conemu.github.io

Also, you can use `Taxi-v3` instead of `Taxi-v2` on windows

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Reg hack:
 - Open Regedit and navigate to HKCU\Console
 - create a DWORD named VirtualTerminalLevel and set the value to hexidecimal 1
 - restart cmd.exe

All credit for this answer goes to BrainSlugs83 in the comments of accepted answer
[How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)